# dequeueOutputBuffer raises IllegalStateException when COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar compatible codec is used

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-mediacodec

I am running this simple `MediaCodec` test on LG G2 with Android 4.4.2:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, 1280, 720);

        int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);

            if (codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
                String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();

                for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                    if (types[j].equalsIgnoreCase(MIME_TYPE)) {
                        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(MIME_TYPE);

                        for(int colorFormat : capabilities.colorFormats) {
                            if (colorFormat == MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar) {

                                format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,     MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
                                format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE,         1000000);
                                format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE,       15);
                                format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 10);

                                MediaCodec mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.getName());

                                mMediaCodec.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
                                mMediaCodec.start();

                                MediaCodec.BufferInfo mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                                mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, 1000);

                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

And it raises the following error:

```
04-21 18:08:29.531    6513-6513/com.example.mediacodec I/OMXClient﹕ Using client-side OMX mux.
04-21 18:08:29.531    6513-6513/com.example.mediacodec E/OMXMaster﹕ A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
04-21 18:08:29.531    6513-6513/com.example.mediacodec I/﹕ @@@VOLOG Info THD 4001A154:    VOOMXPlugin.cpp  VOOMXPlugin  59    open libvoOMXOne.so successfully. 0X5BB9A5B8
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6513/com.example.mediacodec E/﹕ VOLOG Info THD 4001A154 voCOMXBaseConfig.cpp Open 368  The config file vomeOne.cfg could not be opened!
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6513/com.example.mediacodec I/SoftAVCEncoder﹕ Construct SoftAVCEncoder
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec I/OMXClient﹕ Using client-side OMX mux.
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec E/OMXMaster﹕ A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec I/﹕ @@@VOLOG Info THD 60471CD0:    VOOMXPlugin.cpp  VOOMXPlugin  59    open libvoOMXOne.so successfully. 0X5BB9A370
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec E/﹕ VOLOG Info THD 60471CD0 voCOMXBaseConfig.cpp Open 368  The config file vomeOne.cfg could not be opened!
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec I/SoftAVCEncoder﹕ Construct SoftAVCEncoder
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec E/SoftAVCEncoder﹕ internalSetParameter: StoreMetadataInBuffersParams.nPortIndex not zero!
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ OMX_SetParameter() failed for StoreMetaDataInBuffers: 0x80001001
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.encoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -2147483648
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec I/ACodec﹕ setupVideoEncoder succeeded
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6537/com.example.mediacodec E/SoftAVCEncoder﹕ Failed to initialize the encoder: -8
04-21 18:08:29.551    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.encoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
04-21 18:08:29.551    6513-6535/com.example.mediacodec E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
04-21 18:08:29.551    6513-6513/com.example.mediacodec D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-21 18:08:29.551    6513-6513/com.example.mediacodec W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417a8e48)
04-21 18:08:29.551    6513-6513/com.example.mediacodec E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mediacodec, PID: 6513
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mediacodec/com.example.mediacodec.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
            at com.example.mediacodec.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The same error can be reproduced on Sony Xperia ZR. Both devices also support  `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` and it works well with the same parameters. I've tried to run `EncodeDecodeTest` from the `android.media.cts` package and it passes successfully, but it looks like it only tests the first supported color format of the first supported codec which is `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` in this case.

Comment: Note `I/SoftAVCEncoder﹕ Construct SoftAVCEncoder`.  You're using the software AVC codec, not the hardware codec.  It may have different capabilities.  Are you opening multiple codec instances simultaneously?  Note the only behavior you can rely on is the behavior exercised by the CTS tests -- if you do what they do your code is expected to work, if you do something else there's no guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @fadden. Yeah, I've noticed that software codec is being used. I am opening one MediaCodec at a time, I've even tried to run this test on freshly rebooted device and the error still happens. In fact, my app is working fine on both of these devices because I am supporting `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` as well, but  `COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar` is still broken on them (confirmed by above test and by lots of similar errors in production from various devices).

Comment: BTW, on Xperia Z1 I am getting the same `Construct SoftAVCEncoder` log entry for `OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc` codec and `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` color format although it feels like hardware encoder is used (high fps, small CPU load).

Answer (score 0):

at your log,

```
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec E/SoftAVCEncoder﹕ internalSetParameter: StoreMetadataInBuffersParams.nPortIndex not zero!
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ OMX_SetParameter() failed for StoreMetaDataInBuffers: 0x80001001
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.encoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -2147483648
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6536/com.example.mediacodec I/ACodec﹕ setupVideoEncoder succeeded
04-21 18:08:29.541    6513-6537/com.example.mediacodec E/SoftAVCEncoder﹕ Failed to initialize the encoder: -8
```

AVC stopped that nPortIndex is NOT zero. 
see the below link as ref. 
http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/avc/enc/SoftAVCEncoder.cpp#684

```
686            StoreMetaDataInBuffersParams *storeParams =
687                    (StoreMetaDataInBuffersParams*)params;
688            if (storeParams->nPortIndex != 0) {
689                ALOGE("%s: StoreMetadataInBuffersParams.nPortIndex not zero!",
690                        __FUNCTION__);
691                return OMX_ErrorUndefined;
692            }
```

that will make error on SoftAVCEncoder.cpp,

```
150  /** There was an error, but the cause of the error could not be determined */
151  OMX_ErrorUndefined = (OMX_S32) 0x80001001,
```

http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/native/include/media/openmax/OMX_Core.h#151

How about review your config or looking for workaround for this error?